# Android RecyclerView call Activity's methods

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adapter, android-recyclerview

i have an Activity which contains an "Overview"-View and a RecyclerView. (See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcd9hlrset28sps/Screenshot_2015-01-08-17-47-07.png?dl=0)

The overview shows some statistics about the listelements in the RecyclerView. It is initialized in the Activity's class and can be updated by calling initOverview();

The RecyclerView.Adapter for the Listitems implements an onlick to delete specific listitems.

My problem is, that the overview wont be updated automatically when i change the list-data so i want to call the Activity's "initOverview()" from the RecyclerView.Adapter whenever i change the list-data.

Could you help me to accomplish that?

If it helps, here is the Sourcecode: https://github.com/Tak3r07/UniHelper/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/tak3r07/CourseStatistics
AssignmentsActivit.java is the Activity
RecyclerViewAssignmentAdapter.java is the Adapter

Regards 
Tak3r07

Comment: Based on your discription you can achieve this with **observer pattern**

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface with the method between the adapter and the activity.

In the OnClickListener inside the adapter

```
OverviewInterface interface = (OverviewInterface)context;
interface.initOverview();
```

Make an interface class named OverviewInterface

```
public interface OverviewInterface{
   void initOverview();
}
```

Make the activity implement the interface

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OverviewInterface {
    //lots of other code
    public void initOverview(){
      //your code
    }
}
```